# How to send curly braces inside handlebar expression in mandrill?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, mailchimp, mandrill

We are using mandrill to send individual emails. In mandrill, we are using handlebar language to parse metadata which is coming from the application. Now handlebar uses curly braces and our metadata also contain curly braces which results in conflicts while parsing metadata. For example: 
merge_Tags: {
         name: 'redirectUrl',
         content: 'http://somedomain.com/login?{redirect=dashboard}'
            } 
And in mandrill, We have some template where we using these merge variables.

*|redirectUrl|"

Here the curly braces inside curly braces handlebar syntax conflicts at the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent Handlebars escaping by using a "triple-stash", `{{{`

```
{{name}}
{{{content}}}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you try to say. I am using MailChimp language for parsing metadata in mandrill template. The URL which I am sending contains non-alphanumeric character like '{'. So, The URL is no longer working and even not clickable on href tag. I thought to encode the URL and then send to mandrill will work.